# PostgreSQL approach to producing nested JSON from a flat set of records

Tags: json, postgresql

Got an intentionally un-normalized table of data:

```
SELECT location, day, title, teacher, "startTime", "endTime", canceled from "Schedules" ORDER by location, day, "startTime";
```

Data...

```
"First", 1, "Knitting 101", "Doe, John", "2019-02-19T09:00Z", "2019-02-19T11:00Z"
"First", 2, "Model Building 201", "Doe, Jane", "2019-02-20T09:00Z", "2019-02-20T11:00Z"
"Second", 1, "Rocks for Jocks 101", "Smith, Terry", "2019-02-19T09:00Z", "2019-02-19T11:00Z"
"Second", 2, "Speed Reading 101", "Case, Justin", "2019-02-20T09:00Z", "2019-02-20T11:00Z"
```

and want to produce this JSON:

```
[
  {
    "location": "First",
    "days": [
      {
        "day": 1,
        "classes": [
          {
            "title": "Knitting 101",
            "teacher": "Doe, John",
            "starts": "2019-02-19T09:00Z"
            "ends": "2019-02-19T11:00Z",
            "canceled": false
          }
          ... other classes
        ]
      }
      ... other days
    ]
  }
  ... other locations
]
```

Currently taking results of the query and nesting it using a JavaScript function. Trying to use JSON functions unsuccessfully with this approach:

1. (SELECT DISTINCT location FROM "Schedules" locations ORDER BY location) l
2. (SELECT location, day FROM "Schedules" GROUP BY location ORDER BY location, day) d
3. (SELECT * FROM "Schedules" ORDER BY location, day, "startTime") c
4. array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(l)))
5. array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d))) sub-query where d.location = l.location
6. array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(c))) sub-query where c.location = l.location and c.day = d.day

Is this the right way to approach it or am I missing a more elegant solution?

UPDATE: Solution provided by @FXD was to start with the most detailed organization level and work backwards. Here is the working query (small adjustments for quoting mixed case objects:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg("LocationClasses" ORDER BY Location)) AS "FullSchedule"
FROM (
    SELECT location, json_build_object('location', location, 'days', array_to_json(array_agg("LocationDayClasses" ORDER BY day))) AS "LocationClasses"
    FROM (
        SELECT location, day, json_build_object('day', day, 'classes', array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('title', title, 'teacher', teacher,'starts', "startTime", 'ends', "endTime", 'cancelled', canceled) ORDER BY "startTime"))) as "LocationDayClasses"
        FROM "Schedules"
        GROUP BY location, day
    ) T1
    GROUP BY location
) T2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the steps right but IMO in reversed order.
It is possible to do everything in 1 query if you build the classes, group them per location/day, then group all days per location and finally group the entire thing together to have 1 record.

From the query below, I advise you try to see what the `T1` subquery does, then do the same for `T2` subquery. You'll see it wasn't so complicated.

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(LocationClasses ORDER BY Location)) AS FullSchedule
FROM (
    SELECT Location, json_build_object('location',Location, 'days', array_to_json(array_agg(LocationDayClasses ORDER BY day))) AS LocationClasses
    FROM (
        SELECT Location, day, json_build_object('day', Day, 'classes', array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('title',Title,'teacher',Teacher,'starts',Starts,'ends',Ends,'cancelled',false) ORDER BY starts))) as LocationDayClasses
        FROM Schedules
        GROUP BY Location, Day
    ) T1
    GROUP BY Location
) T2
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach worked very nicely and it's pretty easy on the eyes. I tweaked the case, names, and quoting of objects with upper and lower case: